# Which one do I choose

Tags: javascript, python, ruby-on-rails

I'm about to create a web application first but even though I manage the development with rails, graph and react. should I use python thinking more in the future of the application, if it grows in time?    Or if you know about a technology stay first with it for development and then migrate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of option you can choose for web application

1. Use GRAND Stack : GraphQl +Reactjs + Apollo server+ Node js +  Neo4j(instead of this use any other database which you are comfortable)
2. If web app event based : Then user Nodejs as server-side technology (MERN)
3. If web app as Data-computation/ Algorithms solution : then Go we React(Front end) +Nodejs(orchestration/ Middle layer) + Python(application layer/or back-end )+ any DB

Answer (score -1):

Yes, i say every framework is good enough, in the long run every thing comes down to one question, how efficient code did u write?

## Django

You can use django if you are interested in python. It is a famous framework which has its own ORM and many security built in features another option is flask

### I will share my experience.

Recently, coded a website in laravel 5.5, at first everything was fine but when the number of user(s) grew to >50k. The site became slow and my servers showed 100% cpu usage. Later i changed the code, tried to remove nested loops, optimized my queries and used cache technologies like memchached. The site is working fine now.

i hope that answers your question.

I hope the best for you,

**Happy Coding**